# Is it possible for PhpStorm to infer the return type of this method?

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I imagine I might need to add a special annotation somewhere, but I'm crossing my fingers that PhpStorm is smart enough to resolve return types given awkward inheritance patterns.

For example, I have some code that resembles this:

```
<?php

class Collection extends \ArrayObject
{
    public function __construct(array $items)
    {
        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            if (isset(static::$requiredType) && !$item instanceof static::$requiredType)
                $this->offsetSet($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function getFirst()
    {
        return $this->offsetGet(0);
    }
}

class MessageCollection extends Collection
{
    protected static $requiredType = 'Message';
}

class UserCollection extends Collection
{
    protected static $requiredType = 'User';
}
```

I'd like it if when I call `UserCollection::getFirst()` it inferred that a `User` was returned, while when I call `MessageCollection::getFirst()` it inferred that a `Message` was returned. Is there some annotation I could put in somewhere to achieve this result?

My first thought was something like this:

```
    /**
     * @return Message|User|XXXX|YYYY|ZZZZ|AAAA|BBBB|CCCC|DDDD
     */
    public function getFirst()
    {
        return $this->offsetGet(0);
    }
```

but I imagine that would get a little ridiculous to the point of being useless as I add more collection classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/**
 * @method \User getFirst()
 */
class UserCollection extends Collection
{
    protected static $requiredType = 'User';
}
```

Comment: I like this thought. Any chance a similar annotation could work with `foreach` loops too?

Comment: you can use something like this for foreach: `/** @var \User[] $items */`.

Comment: I don't know how I feel about littering comments like that in my code every time I write a foreach loop...

Comment: you can define return type for method, which return collection for foreach . Semthing like this: `@return \User[]`. If you can show example with foreach, maybe i can give advice for it.

Comment: Ah! Figured it out. If you use the class annotation `@method User offsetGet($offset)`, then `foreach ($userCollection as $user)` will infer the correct type for `$user`.